# Increase the area of Word Cloud Plot in R Shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, slider, word-cloud

I'm new to R Shiny and WordCloud. I am creating a wordcloud but for some reason I'm not able to change the area of the plot. I tried changing the values of height and width (in plotOutput) and all it does is change the position of the plot. My UI code for word cloud is:

```
tabPanel("Word Cloud",
         sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
                 
                 sliderInput("numberInput1", "Minimum Frequency:", min=1, max=20, 
                             value=9),
                 sliderInput("numberInput2", "Maximum Number of Words:", min=1, max=500, 
                             value=120),
                 
             ),
             mainPanel(
                 plotOutput("WordCloudPlot",  width = "700px", height="700px")
             )
         )
)
```

My server code for word cloud is:

```
        wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)
        output$WordCloudPlot <- renderPlot({
        wordcloud_rep(names(v), v, scale=c(4,0.6),
                      min.freq = input$numberInput1, max.words=input$numberInput2,
                      colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
        })
```

The plot looks small and something like this:
[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what happens if you set height and width to "100%"?

Comment: When I do that it gives me an error saying "Invalid 'width' or 'height"!

Comment: you get more likely a useful response if you make your code standalone, so that others can copy , paste and run your example without hassle.